# Tensorflow running slow on RTX 2060

Tags: tensorflow

I am following a course on deep learning and I am doing right now the CNN networks the train set is 8000 photos 4000 cats and 4000 dogs the training set is 2000/2000 the size I am using for images is 64x64 with RGB. I am using Keras with 2 conv2d/maxpool layers of 32 filters a flatten layer and two dense layers of 128 and 1 output. My problem is that this setup is performing at 15 minutes per epoch and for 25 epochs that means 6 Hours of training at least plus sometimes on some epochs is freezing for sometimes at 7999/8000 I am running this on windows 10 and anaconda with python 3.7 and TensorFlow 1.13. Is this a good performance or I can improve it? I was expecting from the new Turing architecture better performances.

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Part 1 - Building the convolutional neural network
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=6,
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=6, 
                        allow_soft_placement=True,
                        device_count = {'CPU' : 1,
                                        'GPU' : 1}
                       )

session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

weights = classifier.get_weights()

#Part 2 - Fiting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)

classifier.save("my first model")
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding code that you use.

Comment: Sorry was in the subway will add code later

Comment: i added the code thank you

Comment: Are you using `tensorflow-gpu` or `tensorflow` on the CPU? Does it show it's using the GPU in the console when the training starts?

Comment: Also, 2000 images is a lot, and 2060 doesn't have that many CUDA cores or TPUs. I don't know much about this but I think you have to use FP16 operations to make use of the TPUs.

Comment: I am using tensorflow-gpu and yes is opening Cuda library. 2060 on benchmarks I saw is performing pretty well but i read tensorflow-gpu is built with 3.5 capabilities as default 2060 is performing at 7.5 so I guess I should compile tensorflow by source